# What is good chalk for lecturing?

Tags: education

This question might be odd, but after watching one of [Gilbert Strang's lectures](http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-06-linear-algebra-spring-2010/video-lectures/) I find I am jealous of his great, smoothly flowing chalk that never seems to get dulled down. Anyone know what it is, or a better replacement for the "crayola types"?

Comment: You may be interested in [this MO thread](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/26267/where-to-buy-premium-white-chalk-in-the-u-s-like-they-have-at-rims), though the problem to be solved there wasn't smooth flow but hands not getting chalky. See also [this MO thread](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/58168/good-chalk-in-the-uk) about good chalk in the UK.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I had completely forgotten about this question and came across it again recently, so I decided to email Dr. Strang. To my surprise, he responded almost immediately. The chalk he used is called ***Railroad Chalk***, and you can find it at many popular online retailers.